# How do I define pair CSS class in CSS module (React)?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

```
          <NavLink
            to={rootPath + path}
            activeClassName="active"
            className={scss.navlink}
          >
            <ListItem button key={name}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Icon htmlColor="#E1F5FE" />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
```

In the above code I defined `navlink` class in my `x.module.scss` file as:

```
.navlink {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navlink:hover,
.navlink:active,
.navlink:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Styling for when the link is active */
.navlink.active {
  background-color: #039BE5;
}
```

Notice `.navlink.active` does not actually work as `*imported_class_navlink active` in react.

What can I do to allow `.navlink.active` to work?

Also `.navlink > *` doesn't seem to work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using class modules, use it as class modules

```
          <NavLink
            to={rootPath + path}
            activeClassName={scss.active}
            className={scss.navlink}
          >
            <ListItem button key={name}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Icon htmlColor="#E1F5FE" />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </ListItem>
          </NavLink>
```

If you want to use it as normal class, then use `:global()`

```css
.navlink:global(.active) {
  background-color: #039BE5;
}
```